# MainScreen + Persistable in one BlackBerry class

Tags: model-view-controller, blackberry, storage, persistent

I have few classes for my Blackberry application right now. Now what I am doing is to create one screen for user to enter their information, store it inside the persistent storage, so that when they click Back on the navigation button, all the information they typed will be displayed on a list view.

My question is, I cannot create a class that extends MainScreen and implements Persistable at the same time because it will give me error.

How to solve this problem?

To make it easier for you guys to see, this is the fragment of the class that I have.

```
inMenu.add(new MenuItem ("Save",110,10)
    {
        public void run()
        {
            synchronized(uv.store)
            {
                Vector _data = (Vector) UserVector.store.getContents();
                if (_data == null) 
                {
                    _data = new Vector();
                    UserVector.store.setContents(_data);
                }

                UserVector newRec = new UserVector();

                newRec.setElement(UserVector.TITLE,titleLabel.getText());
                newRec.setElement(UserVector.VENUE,venueLabel.getText());
                newRec.setElement(UserVector.DESCRIPTION,descriptionLabel.getText());

                _data.addElement(newRec);
                UserVector.store.commit();  
            }
            Dialog.inform("Information Saved!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: What error do you get when you try to combine them?

Comment: It says something like this :

Comment: mypackage.SchedulerCreateNew: Error!: Class mypackage.SchedulerCreateNew marked Persistable by interface: net.rim.device.api.util.Persistable is not Persistable: base Class net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen does not implement net.rim.vm.Persistable

Answer (score 1):

You are witnessing true proof of BlackBerry programming not being Java: the fact that an interface (Persistable) is not inherited.

In BlackBerry, if you want to persist a class, marking it as Persistable isn't enough. The entire class hierarchy upwards should be persistable. At the same time, marking a class Persistable would make you think that a subclass will inherit persistable, but it doesn't. You'll have to explicitly mark the subclass as Persistable. (I know, at this point you are probably thinking about this being an heresy, an atrocity, an ..., well, BlackBerry programming is full of tricky things like this). Think of `Persistable` as a marker interface which is not inherited.

In your case, you have a Runtime error telling you that in order to persist your screen, you'd have to make `MainScreen` implement `Persistable`, which of course you can't because you don't have access to the source code. Even if you could, there's another caveat: every field, collection, container in your screen should also be Persistable for the thing to work, otherwise you'd get an exception. So you are completely out of luck here because neither `Field` or its subclasses do implement `Persistable`.

But in any case, even if it were possible, it is not advisable to save an entire View (with its many nested objects) just for convenience. Instead, save the content of the fields and screen state in an small container object (implementing `Persistable`) and restore the screen when entering the app. This approach allows you to reuse your container object in case new Fields are added or removed from the GUI (otherwise you'd have to clean simulator memory each time you change the GUI design to avoid `ClassCastException` loading the screen from persistence). Because you are decoupling GUI from persistence, it also allows you to choose which fields are saved and which ones don't need to.

Comment: Sorry for my bad understanding in this. Does it means that I should have one class implementing Persistable to manage all the stored data while another class which will be the editfield, saving, editing, removing and everything?

Comment: Yes. Not only is the only way to go (because of BlackBerry's very particular implementation) it is also good design: you will be following the Single Responsibility Principle, and avoiding inheritance-related issues. I recommend it even in other platforms where your idea might have worked.

Comment: I see. May I know how to access/retrieve the stored data from the persistent class to the viewing class? I attached my code above, please help me fix it. I know it might be very horrible but I am still learning all of these.

Comment: Have a look here, it is better explained: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/36691/Storing_objects_persistently_1554312_11.jsp

Answer (score 0):

A MainScreen is a very complex class with many user interface elements in it. Even if you could persist an entire MainScreen I can't imagine why you would want to. The MVC pattern suggests that you keep the model (your persistent store) separate from your view and controllers.

It is probably easies to combine the view and controller in the MainScreen, but you can separate them out.

Another argument for not putting extraneous stuff in your persistent store, is every time you change it you have to either provide for migrating the old format storage to the new format, or force your users to re-enter the data again.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts @Richard , actually after reading so much articles about MVC I did not get the clear concept about how does MVC really works in Java programming. Therefore most of my coding is just a collection of trial and error attempts.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it your `UserVector` class should implement `Persistable` and should have static methods for storing and retrieving a UserVector object from persistent memory.

Check out http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Persistent_data_storage_509562_11.jsp for a good introduction to persistent storage.

Persistent memory is a bit like the Windows registry. You can lookup objects using a unique key, manipulate them, then save them back there as long as they are serializable (persistable). Do not try to save anything to do with your UI into persistent memory, only save data.

Also, if you are saving many user data, you might be better off looking at an [SQLite database for storage](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/index.jsp?name=SQLite%20-%20Development%20Guide%20-%20BlackBerry%20Java%20Applications5.0&language=English&userType=21&category=Java%20Development%20Guides%20and%20API%20Reference&subCategory=).